# How to get a serialized array from a client form to a server using the GM_xmlhttpRequest

Tags: jquery, json, serialization, greasemonkey, gm-xmlhttprequest

I used JQuery.serializeArray() on a form to create an array of objects on a GreaseMonkey application:

```
[
  {
    name: a
    value: 1
  },
  {
    name: b
    value: 2
  },
  {
    name: c
    value: 3
  },
  {
    name: d
    value: 4
  },
  {
    name: e
    value: 5
  }
]
```

I need to use GM_xmlhttpRequest to serve these fields back to a server side application.  What is the best way to return these fields?

Thanks in advance,

D

Answer (score 2):

I think I found the answer...

I need to use

```
JSON.stringify(obj)
```

to turn my serialized fields into a json string.  Then I should be able to serve that string to the server as one of the data arguments in a GM_xmlhttpRequest POST request.